What are downsides of using composite types and array type columns in TimescaleDB hypertable?
I'm considering to use a composite type, array of standard type and array of composite type columns in TimescaleDB hypertable. I'm curious whether using such columns has any downsides like less effective compression comparing to using standard scalar data types?

I cannot say if TimescaleDB has any specific problems with such data types (by expectation is "no"), but usually it is a bad idea in general to use arrays or composite types in a table definition. Unless you have a compelling reason to do that, don't do it.

Why is it a bad idea?

I makes INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT more complicated, and there is no benefit.

To me the benefit is that with arrays a variable number of items can be stored along with other row data (locally) thus getting it does not require joins and random access to other tables

As long as you never need to update individual array elements, join via them or otherwise manipulate the elements of the array, you have a point.
